# Event listener is only being assigned to the first class that is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to add event listeners to the appropriate html elements.

```
var eventArray = [['scribbler', 'click', addNote], ['checkbox', 'change', strikethrough]];

for(var i=0;i<=eventArray.length; i++){
  addEvents(eventArray[i][0], eventArray[i][1], eventArray[i][2]);
}
```

The above function loops through the provided array and supplies the `addEvents` function with the proper parameters.

```
function addEvents(className, event, fn){
  var g = document.getElementsByClassName(className); 
  for(var i=0; i<=g.length; i++){
    g[i].addEventListener(event, fn, false);
  }
}
```

This is the `addEvents` function that is called in the `for` loop. It works for the first run-through, but anything after that seems to be ignored. I.e. the scribbler/click event listener is properly applied but the checkbox/change one is not. If I reverse the order of the array then the properly applied listeners are also flipped.

I have tried hard resetting the `g` variable at the end of the `addEvents` function but that did not seem to work.

`document.getElementsByClassName(className).each.addEventListener(event, fn, false);`

This does not seem like an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace `<=` in your code with `<` as you are probably getting some error like `Cannot read property addEventListener of undefined`

the reason for that change is that if your `array` has, let's say, 3 elements, their indexes are: `0, 1, 2`, and `array.length` is `3`

with `<=` your loop will iterate from `0` to `3` inclusive, giving you `undefined`

Comment: So I was overshooting my NodeList by one iteration and that was causing the second call to not take place? Edit: your edit answered that question, thank you.

Comment: more or less, you should look at your browser's console to get more information